# Customized Time Picker

Tags: gwt, gwt-openlayers

How can I create my own Time picker in my GWT RPC application. I have used a standard time picker from traccar.But it has used a drop down time field which has time interval of 30 mins.I want it for 1 min time interval. What are the changes I have to make in my  Ui Binder class?